# Как правильно использовать акселерометр?

Tags: java, android

У меня тут такая проблема я использую акселерометр, но он, я так понял, определяет положение телефона относительно сторон света(Север, юг и т.д) и плюс использует магнитные поля (`Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`), и из-за этого мои показатели всегда изменяются +/- на 10 в разные стороны, хотя девайс стоит на месте.

Может есть способ точно измерить положение осей X Y Z? Может ли гироскоп дать такую возможность? Чтоб если телефон стоит на месте, то показатели не прыгают и правильно отображаются.

Answer (score 2):

Такие изменяемые данные обычно определяют не на конкретный момент времени, а как среднее значение на промежуток. Собирайте данные в течении некого периода и берите из них среднее.